# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ts_user is not mapped [from ts_user]

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been searched this problem for a long time, but the answers didn't help.

The results are the same, maybe the reasons are different.

The model associated with database by using Table annotation.

The model as follows:

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "ts_user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String phone;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The DAO as follows:

```html
@Repository
public class HibernateUserDAO implements UserDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateUserDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    private Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> list() {
        Session session  = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        List<User> users = session.createQuery("from ts_user").list();
        session.close();
        return users;
    }
}
```

xml as follows:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using table name and not the entityName in here. Entity name, i.e. name of the class, should be used in here.

```
@Override
public List<User> list() {
    Session session  = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<User> users = session.createQuery("select u from User u").list();
    session.close();
    return users;
}
```